# RangeSelector with MultipleSeries

Tags: javascript, canvas, dygraphs

I understand that the range selector shows the average for multiple series. Is there a way to choose a particular series as the range selector series. Is there a method i can override to modify the behaviour of the range selector drawing.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option for this, but there is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=450).

A workaround would be to have two synchronized charts, one which is all range slider and one which is all chart. http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I tweaked the source code in order to achieve this. It is showing only
values of a single graph in the miniplot now